# Using a search bar to find items in a list

Tags: pyqt5

I want to use a line edit as a search bar in order to find items in a Qlistwidget. I also want the qlistwidget to scroll up/down (in search) as text is being changed in the line edit.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QWidget, QListWidget, QLineEdit


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.ListBox = QListWidget()
        self.ListBox.insertItem(0,'Temperature')
        self.ListBox.insertItem(1,'Mass')
        self.ListBox.insertItem(2,'Length')
        self.ListBox.insertItem(3,'Height')
        self.ListBox.insertItem(4,'Width')
        self.ListBox.insertItem(5,'Volume')
        self.ListBox.insertItem(6,'Surface_Area')
        self.ListBox.insertItem(7,'Material')
        self.ListBox.insertItem(8,'Location')
        self.ListBox.insertItem(9,'Strength')
        self.ListBox.insertItem(10,'Color')
        self.Search_Bar = QLineEdit()
        layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.ListBox)
        layout.addWidget(self.Search_Bar)
        self.Search_Bar.textChanged.connect(self.Search)


    def Search(self):
        if self.Search_Bar.text() == 'Strength':
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internally implemented `match` function provided by all Qt item models is usually faster than cycling through the list via Python.

```py
    def Search(self, text):
        model = self.ListBox.model()
        match = model.match(
            model.index(0, self.ListBox.modelColumn()), 
            QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, 
            text, 
            hits=1, 
            flags=QtCore.Qt.MatchStartsWith)
        if match:
            self.ListBox.setCurrentIndex(match[0])
```

This will automatically select and scroll to the first item found (if any).